# SwiftUI does not evaluate elseif correctly?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am creating a SwiftUI view where I have three possible conditions, and want to show different content based on which condition is met. A simplified example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var condition1 = true
    @State var condition2 = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if condition1 {
                Text("text1")
            } else if condition2 {
                Text("text2")
            } else {
                Text("text3")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.condition2 = true
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
                self.condition1 = false
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.0) {
                self.condition2 = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen:
1) The UI shows `text1` when the app starts
2) The UI still shows `text1` after 2 seconds (both variables are `true`)
3) The UI shows `text2` after 4 seconds (`condition2` is `true` but `condition1` is now `false`)
4) The UI shows `text3` after 6 seconds (both variables are now `false`)

What actually happens:
1) The UI shows `text1` when the app starts
2) The UI shows `text1` after 2 seconds
3) The UI shows `text2` after 4 seconds
**4) The UI continues to show `text2` after 6 seconds**

Weirdly enough, if I put breakpoints in the UI code, the line showing text3 is executed, it just seems the UI never updates. Even more weirdly, if I put a `Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 0)` in that else case, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug in SwiftUI or what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually if to add buttons and switch states on buttons then all works, so this is something with delayed updates (maybe racing, maybe bug... did not dig further)

Here is actually solution, which works (tested with Xcode 11.2 /iOS 13.2) ... separate those conditional dependent views into dedicated view builder, like below

```
struct TestRefreshOnCondition: View {
    @State var condition1 = true
    @State var condition2 = false

    var ConditionalView: some View {
        Group {
            if condition1 {
                Text("text1")
            } else if condition2 {
                Text("text2")
            } else {
                Text("text3")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ConditionalView
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.condition2 = true
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
                self.condition1 = false
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.0) {
                self.condition2 = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```